# App developed by Objective-c is run on simulator and ipad mini with version 9.1. But did not run on iPhone 5s of version 10.1

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode8, ios10, iphone-5

`ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/nfonics/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuseumApp-hjhjdsxjqjpxkjcecmzyuvmpgbfe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libXCDYouTubeKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/nfonics/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuseumApp-hjhjdsxjqjpxkjcecmzyuvmpgbfe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libXCDYouTubeKit.a
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/nfonics/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuseumApp-hjhjdsxjqjpxkjcecmzyuvmpgbfe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libYTVimeoExtractor.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (arm64): /Users/nfonics/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MuseumApp-hjhjdsxjqjpxkjcecmzyuvmpgbfe/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libYTVimeoExtractor.a
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewControllerDidReceiveVideoNotification", referenced from:
      -[StopItemListViewController playYouTubeVideos:] in StopItemListViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in StopViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in StopItemListViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_YTVimeoExtractor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in StopViewController.o
  "_XCDMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishErrorUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[StopViewController moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:] in StopViewController.o
      -[StopItemListViewController moviePlayerPlaybackDidFinish:] in StopItemListViewController.o
  "_XCDYouTubeVideoUserInfoKey", referenced from:
      -[StopViewController videoPlayerViewControllerDidReceiveVideo:] in StopViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`
[When app run on the iPhone 5S with version 10.1 shows these error. App always run on simulator and iPad mini](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gztRR.png)

Comment: Please post you debug output here and not an image. Also post your code.

Comment: added the error showing while run on iPhone. Please take a look.

Comment: Seem like the library you use 'libXCDYouTubeKit` has no support for ARM64. Update your library or build from source.